# VUEJS: passing value of javascript button

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to pass the value of a button to a function when it is clicked. Because the buttons were created as a javascript element I'm not sure how to do it.

```
    methods:{
      createButtons() {
        
        var i;
        var rows =["9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1","0","•","="];
        var elDiv = document.getElementById("myDIV");
        for (i=0; i<12; i++){ 
          var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
          btn.value = i
          btn.style.height = "40px"
          btn.textContent = rows[i];
          btn.onclick = buttonvalue;
          elDiv.appendChild(btn);  
        }
        var pressedbutton = document.getElementById("calculate");
        pressedbutton.remove();
      },
    }
  }

function buttonvalue(i){
  alert(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an XY problem. Don't create DOM elements manually like this, that's what Vue is for.

But to answer your question, you can do something like this:

```js
const captureI = i;
btn.onclick = () => buttonvalue(captureI);
```

I copied `i` into a new local variable because `i` changes value by the `for` loop.

Or you can just write the `for` loop like this instead:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  // ... omitted code ...
  btn.onclick = () => buttonvalue(i);
}
```